# how to avoid creating new columns in database

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I have a table of dentists and services. And I want it to be dynamic so I have added a "add services" function. but how can I normalize it if services are not defined yet? since I didn't add yet.

the solution I've made is that I created a new table which is specialty where it creates new column every time I added a new service. But I dont know if it's very improper to create a new column within the add services function itself. But that's the only way I think. Are there any ways to solve it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Im sorry, I have removed it. Im also new to stackoverflow. Still learning how to properly use this platform thank you for understanding!

Comment: _Now_ it lacks any proper context. Explain your data model.

Comment: You need to replace the pictures with equivalent text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting is worth reading first

Comment: Anyway it sounds like you need a dentists table, a services table, and then a dentist-services table as a link between services and dentists. Read about many-to-many relationships. Then in the situation you described you can add an entry to the services table, get its new ID and then add an entry to the dentist-services table with the ID of the service and the ID of the selected dentist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic columns are not good at all!
Tables should be static to be reliable.

**Use relation-tables instead.**

###### Example

You have a `dentists` table. It has an `id` column as primary-key.

Create a `services` table. Of course it should have a primary-key. besides that, put a `dentist_id` column. This will contain the `id` of the dentist in the `dentists` table.

If you provide more information and code or database schema, we maybe able to help more.

#### EDIT

As [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) mentioned, if it is possible that multiple dentists work on one service, do a many-to-many relation.

###### Example

You have a `dentists` table And a `services` table. They both have an `id` column as primary-key.

Create a `r_dentist_service` table. Of course it should have a primary-key. besides that, put a `dentist_id` column and a `service_id` column. These should contain the respective IDs. This table will relate dentists to services.

Comment: Note that this assumes that each service can only be provided by one dentist. Whereas you might imagine that all dentists would offer common services such as fillings, crowns etc. So maybe a many to many structure would be more likely to be suitable.

Comment: You are right. I'll complete the answer.